# unity 2d grid not showing up when I zoom in

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I recently changed my 2d Unity game to 3d by clicking the 2d button just to explore the editor but when I went back to 2d, things were not working and the grid would disappear when I zoom in. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: When finally at a loss. Restart unity.

Comment: @BugFinder I tried that, It didn't work.

Comment: ive flipped between 2d and 3d many times, id suggest you somehow changed the grid settings..

Comment: Try selecting an object and pressing "f" to focus on it.  Press it multiple time until at closest view.

Answer (score -1):

Try selecting an object and pressing "f" to focus on it. Press it multiple times until at closest view.